# Can cold weather cause a potty trained child to wet the bed again?

Tags: sleep, potty-training, bed-wetting

My four year old daughter has not wet the bed in about a year.  A few nights ago (on an unexpectedly cold night) she did.  There are several questions here about bed wetting and regression, but I'm specifically wondering about being cold at night being a trigger for bed wetting.  A web search reveals a couple of message board anecdotes, but I was hoping for something more concrete.

Can being cold at night cause a child to wet the bed again?

Comment: If it's just a one-off, I wouldn't consider it regression. At 4 it's common to have the occasional accident.

Comment: Did this also happen around a time change? My twins, one fully trained, the other partially, had accidemts after the switch to dst.

Comment: I... wet my bed the last time when I was... uh, 34.  The previous time before that was... 28... I don't think I'm regressing, but it does happen lol...

Comment: @mkennedy You may be on to something!  It **was** after the time change, and the last time she did it, she had massive jet lag.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone.  It hasn't happened again, so I'll just (happily) let it go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, things that contribute to my children wetting the bed are primarily one of three things:

- Drinking more before/during bedtime
- Sleeping more soundly
- Barriers to getting up to go in the middle of the night

(Plus of course forgetting to go right before bed.)

How could cold affect these?

- When it's cold outside, it's also *dry*.  That means the child may be thirstier, and thus drink more before/during bedtime.
- Some children may sleep more soundly in the cold, though it's more common that sleep is sounder in warmth.  But, your child may have dressed more warmly and/or put on more covers than usual, and thus ended up sleeping more soundly.
- Having all of those covers on would be a substantial barrier to going to the bathroom in the middle of the night.  It also would be cold getting out of them - another barrier.

All that said, given the n=1 nature of this occurrence, I wouldn't read too much into it.  Yes, it's possible it's related to the cold.  It's also possible she just had an accident.  That's entirely normal and to be expected until 6 or so, from what I recall (and some kids, even older than that). I wouldn't see it as regression at all.

Answer (score 1):

My son, age 6, consistently wets himself when we ski. I've tried making him go to the toilet right before we change into ski gear, restricting liquids, a combination of both and threats. I genuinely believe the cold itself is the trigger. He's been fully toilet trained and dry through the night since age 2 but something about the extreme cold means he can't even feel himself wee.